# Binary - Hexa - Integer - Data cast and processing

Tags: python

I'm looking for a Python3 lib or an implemented way to process on binary data.
The example will tell you more than words :

first part of the packet:

```
packet.data1 = '0x0EDD'
```

I want to separate the beginning from the 2 last bits so i use the arrays methodes:

```
my_id = int(bin(int(packet.data1,16))[-2:],2)
my_len_of_len = int(bin(int(packet.data1,16))[:-2],2)
```

Now in the second part if my_len_of_len equals 1 i have to catch the following byte like :

```
packet.data2 = '0x08'
```

And then i have to convert it to int to know the number of bytes are following, they are the content of the message:

```
my_len = int(packet.data2,16)
```

And now i can catch the message from the data. I'm trying to understand a game protocol but with the methods i know, it's "slow" and hard to find myself with all array indices.

A solution for me ?

Thank you.

Comment: why your data is a string ? Can't you get it as bytes ? Use bitwise operators - `integer & 3` gets two last bits - `0x0EDD & 3` gives you `my_id`

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/bitwise_operators_example.htm

Comment: @furas great points you should post as answer and provide some explanation.  I learned quite a bit following your hints

Comment: My datas come from the Wireshark buffer using PyShark so they are in base 16.
I'll give bitwise operators a try but shouldn't i use struct to unpack datas from my bytes objects ?
And i don't know why my data is a string. When i convert from integer to bin there is 0b added before (or something like that).

If i use struct, can i catch a single Unsigned Short and catch the other bits in the original container ? I have to read from buffer unsignedShort, Short, Double after the first process i showed you.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a library for this. My personal recommendation is the awesome [construct](https://github.com/construct/construct) library.

Methods such as what you've started with, using bit-wise operators or using `struct.unpack` are highly error-prone and difficult to maintain.